# matplotlib xlim/ylim adjustment difficulty

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm using matplotlib to display image data in my PyQt 4 application. I'm zooming in at runtime by setting the "xlim" and "ylim" values. This works very well. However, if the widget that contains the plot is resized, matplotlib will (rightly) respect the xlim/ylim values I have set and will then adjust the size of the plot. What I would like is to be able to resize the containing widget so that it appears to obscure the plot as the user shrinks it, or uncovers more of the plot as the user enlarges it.

Does anyone know if there is a setting or property that allows for this? I seem to have conflicting requirements: the user must be able to zoom in by adjusting the axes limits, but when resizing the limits should then adjust automatically to display more (or less) of the plot as the container changes size. I'm not sure if this is possible. Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could show your code, you could also show pictures of what you get and what you want to get.

Comment: It's definitely possible. It may just be a bit of work to handle all the possible cases seperately. What exactly is the mechanism that allows you to zoom in at runtime? Is this done via the matplotlib zooming tools? How would you get back to the original zoom status? It's of course best if you provide a [mcve] of the issue, because then people can help you more easily.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far guys. I've been thinking about this and I agree with "ImportanceOfBeingEarnest". It's a lot of work to handle all the cases. I believe the way to go about it is to handle the resize event of the containing widget, determine what the new xlim and ylim values should be based on the new size, and alter them to give the illusion of uncovering more of the image as the container is enlarged. I'm going to leave this for later though and come back to it if I have time as it seems like a lot of work for pure visuals. Thanks again.